# Python enum34 like interface for boost python enum

Tags: python, c++, boost, enums

I would like to get an enum by string similar to the enum34 package:

Color[‘red’] == Color.red

If I do this with a boost::python enum I get:

TypeError: 'type' object has no attribute '**getitem**'

Of course the boost version has no **getitem** method. So to add this method to a class, I need to overwrite the metaclass, but changing this on an already defined class looks very fishy. Another possibility would be to create some proxy-class, but I don’t know how to apply this easily on a global scale (methods returning the proxy, structs containing the proxy instead of the original class …)
Are there any other possibilities?

Comment: Just found another way which is implemented directly in C++:

 1. Get the PyTypeObject from ob_type of the boost::python::enum_
 2. Make a copy of this PyTypeObject (because this is shared by all boost enums)
 3. add a PyMappingMethods struct to tp_as_mapping with the __getitem__ function
 4. add the modified PyTypeObject as new  ob_type

Comment: Add that as an answer, and then accept it in two days.  :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm using now the following workaround:

```
PyObject *enum_type = reinterpret_cast<PyObject *>(testEnum.ptr());

// get the metatype and make a copy
PyTypeObject *pto = reinterpret_cast<PyTypeObject *>(enum_type->ob_type);
PyTypeObject *new_pto = new PyTypeObject();
memcpy(new_pto, pto, sizeof(PyTypeObject)); 

// define a new mapping method
PyMappingMethods *mapping = new PyMappingMethods();
mapping->mp_subscript = convertEnum,

// replace the old mapping method and overwrite the meta type in the enum
new_pto->tp_as_mapping = mapping;
enum_type->ob_type = new_pto;
```

and the enum conversion function:

```
static PyObject* convertEnum(PyObject *self, PyObject *args) {
    auto resultEnum = enumfromString(PyString_AsString(args));
    return incref(object(resultEnum).ptr());
}
```

Source with python test can be found in https://github.com/CymricNPG/cpython/tree/enum